# can´t list key in array

Tags: react-hooks, use-state

Dear knowledgeable SO members!
I´m trying to list player.id, player.number and player.totPoints
I have this code:

```
const [number, setNumber] = useState('')
```

const [totPoints, setTotPoints] = useState(0)
const [players, setPlayers] = useState([]);

```
        const addHandler = () => {
          const newTotPoints = setTotPoints(prevState => prevState + 1)
          setPlayers([...players, {
                id: players.length,
                number: number,
              totPoints: newTotPoints
                      }])
        }
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Points scored</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody> 
            {
             players.map(player => (
             <tr>
            <td>{player.id}</td>
            <td>{player.number}</td>
            <td>{player.totPoints}</td>
          </tr> ))
              
            }
          
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

and can´t list player.totPoints as [you can see](https://codepen.io/lelkes/pen/xxgNwwO)

Hope you can help mee

Comment: Hey, 
you can directly use `totPoints` instead of `newTotPoints`

Comment: Thanks Alan, but that doesn´t solve my problem with not showing the `totPoints`